# RubyGem railties cannot be found after running "git push heroku master"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku, aptana3

So here is my situation which is quiet strange. Using Aptana (Installed rails via rubyinstaller) I have my application pushed up into heroku stack cedar with the following GemFile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
#Added Web Design Framework
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.0'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.0'
end

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.4'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.0'
group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

I have tried changing the source from https to http however the point is that after this push and following error, rails is gone literally! rails -v command leads to the error that coud not load rubygem!Ruby is there but rails -v is not working anymore. Any help will be appreciated, folks!

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.pre
   Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs bin/
   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
   Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
   In Gemfile:
   rails (= 3.2.3) ruby depends on
   railties (= 3.2.3) ruby
   jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
   railties (3.2.4.rc1)

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's basically a dependency conflict. `jquery-rails` needs a newer version of `railties` than the one `rails` requires.

To solve it (at least what I could do to solve it in a local test app), simply bump the required version of `jquery-rails` from 2.0.0 to 2.0.2. Alternatively, you could upgrade `rails` to 3.2.4 or .5, I suspect.

Generally speaking, gems should be required with `~>` rather than `=`, ie

```
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 2.0.0"
```

rather than

```
gem "jquery-rails", "2.0.0"
```

This way Bundler can use gem versions 2.0.X rather than just 2.0.0, giving Bundler greater leeway finding a dependency tree that'll work out for the app. And it won't make your app dependencies more fragile, as the actual, working versions will be locked in `Gemfile.lock` and only updated when you want them to.

Answer (score 0):

I would try and deploy again, could have been a bad connection to rubygems.

Comment: Can't be, I already tried like 10 times. The point is, after this error I need to re-install rails. I do it and then I push and still, problem is there! I dunno y the rails is gone after an unsuccessful push?!

Comment: Best contact heroku support in this case.

Comment: Funny thing is that while rails -v works outside of the app directory, all gem related files are not working inside the directory. Even bundle install not working!